# How to set menu background in android 2.3

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to set a color background to my welcome menu. I looked for a solution but I didn't find one good for me. I'm working with android 2.3 API

my welcome_menu code:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_preferiti"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_preferiti"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_preferiti_pressed"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_sicuro_bici"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_navigazionesicura"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_sicuro_bici_pressed"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_credits"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/menu_credits"
    android:icon="@drawable/menu_credits_pressed"/>
```

WelcomeActivity code to create menu

```
    @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    Intent intent = null;
    switch (item.getItemId())
    {
    case R.id.menu_preferiti:
        // CAMBIARE LA QUERY!!! METTERE QUELLA DEL RECUPERO DEI PREFERITI CON JOIN!!!
        daos = new DAOService(this);
        ArrayList<Itinerario> listafav = daos.doRetriveAllItinerari();
        intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, FavoriteActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("lista_favoriti", listafav);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_sicuro_bici:
        intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, NavigazioneSicuraActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;

    case R.id.menu_credits:
       intent = new Intent(WelcomeActivity.this, CreditsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        return true;


    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Maybe a solution is to create a style for menu, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. However you can display your own custom menu and handle it with `onKeyDown()`